# dynamodb ttl attribute and RCU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does  configuring TTL attribute in dynamo DB impact RCU. If dynamo DB has to expire any item based on TTL value, does it consume allocated RCU.

I did not find specific documentation on creating TTL in dynamo and impact on RCU configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html)

> Deletes performed via TTL are **not counted towards** capacity units or request units. TTL deletes are available at no additional cost.

This process is actually taken care of in the background, so you might actually notice for a brief time after the TTL the item is still here as the delete has been queued to be processed.

Comment: A follow up question if I add DAX accelerator end point in front of dynamo db, Then is it required the DAX TTL should be less than Dynamo DB TTL. So the cache does not have stale entry,

Comment: The TTL attribute in DynamoDB is a timestamp per each item, the TTL in DAX will be an offset from the current time based on the query. If your application cannot have stale data then yes make the cache less.